# How do I convert a JSON HTTP Response to Hash?

Tags: perl, http

I have this code to get a response from a web service I'm running

```
use JSON;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
$response= get $url;
print $response;
```

this is what is printed out:

```
{"error":0,"string":"4^2=16","answer":16.0}
```

How to I convert this JSON string into a hash so I can do something also the lines of:

```
print $response_hash{"answer"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $response = '{"error":0,"string":"4^2=16","answer":16.0}';

my $hash = JSON->new->decode($response);

say $hash->{answer};
```

If you can't install modules, then [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) has been part of the standard Perl distribution since 5.14.0 and has a very similar interface.

Comment: If you're going to install a module, might as well make it Cpanel::JSON::XS. If you just install JSON, then you'll end up using the slow JSON::PP behind the scenes anyway.